# XD it Flutter plugin not exporting widgets

Tags: flutter, adobe-xd

I am using Adobe XD by installing XD to Flutter, a plugin. But suddenly, there is no response when I click Export All Widgets or Export Widget. I'm flustered because it worked until just a moment ago.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TmKXt.png)

I managed other settings, turning those settings off and on, and saved the file again as a different name, but there is still no response.
The only difference is that elements are grouped in Xd.